# How to get length of C string in Zig

Tags: zig

I built a binary dynamic library as `zig build-lib -dynamic string_utils.zig` for the below code:

```rs
const std = @import("std");

pub fn joinStrings(firstname: []const u8, lastname: []const u8, buf: *[]u8) !void {
    var stream = std.io.fixedBufferStream(buf.*);
    var writer = stream.writer();

    try writer.print("Hello, {s} {s}!", .{ firstname, lastname });

    buf.* = stream.getWritten();
}
```

Then created the `string.utls.h` file as:

```
void joinStrings(const char* firstname, const char* lastname, char** buf);
```

Then created my `main.zig` file as below:

```rs
const std = @import("std");
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("string_ptr.h");
});

pub fn main() !void {
    var buf: [*c]u8 = undefined;
    c.joinStrings("Hasan", "Yousef", &buf);
    const len = // how to read the length of the buf for memory allocation //
    const greetings = std.mem.sliceFromRaw(u8, buf[0..len]);
    std.debug.print("Saved string: {s}\n", .{greetings});
}
```

1. How can I get the size required for memory allocation?
2. Is my approach in creating this lib and calling it correct, or wromg, or can be enhanced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the length of a C string, you can use the [`std.mem.len`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.len) function.